# Pattern matching, percentage match for multiple datasets

Tags: pattern-matching

hope this is the right place to ask this!

I have no development experience but I'm looking to recruit someone to create a web app that can do what, as far as I can tell, is called "pattern matching."

Basically I want to compare two data sets to calculate a percentage of "overlap," for instance.

Set One:

1. A
2. A
3. B

Set Two:

1. B
2. A
3. B

But I'd like to do this over many, many instances/comparisons (perhaps hundreds of thousands).  Does anyone have any idea what technologies/languages etc would be necessary to implement something like this and what questions I can ask to make sure the person I'm interviewing is capable of implementing it?

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: I'm confused by your problem description. A set contains distinct values but both of your examples have duplicate `A` and `B`. What score do you expect from them?

Comment: Please don't post the same question on multiple sites..... [DBA](http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/118301/72091) and [DataScience](http://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/8470)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about screening candidates for recruitment.

Comment: Sorry, but it is unlikely you will get any Stack Exchange site to answer this question in its current form. The problem description is not clear enough to give a technical answer, and the goals of getting technology stack described and/or screening questions for interview are not suitable for the SE sites (also, with the vague problem description, a broad range of answers is possible). You might find your general problem (how to recruit a technical specialist who can solve something when you don't know the area) works in http://startups.stackexchange.com/ or has already been answered there

Answer (score 0):

You use the wrong words for everything...

- your "sets" are actually *lists*
- you want to compute the similarity, but not *match* them
- there is no notion of a "pattern" in your problem

What you are looking for is **similarity** of lists, but a very basic form that you just have to *do*, there will be no tool or question to help you, because **it's just counting**. People don't write tutorials for counting.